# PowerBI Show Status of Item As of Max Date in Slicer

Tags: powerbi, analytics, dax

I have a number of items that can change their status tag over time, but I only want to show the most recent status that falls within the date range of a slicer that is applied.

[image]

As of April 10 2019, the following should occur:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a measure that returns a string value of the last status, such as "Green", "Yellow" or "Red".

In this example, I'm assuming the historical item status table referred to as "Item Status", and there are separate "Calendar" and "Item" tables for date and item dimensions respectively.

```
Current Status = 
IF (
    HASONEVALUE( 'Item'[Item] ),
    VAR MaxSelectedDate = MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
    VAR LastUpdatedDate = CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Item Status'[Date] ),
        REMOVEFILTERS( 'Calendar' ),
        'Calendar'[Date] <= MaxSelectedDate
    )
    RETURN CALCULATE (
        VALUES ( 'Item Status'[Status] ),
        REMOVEFILTERS( 'Calendar' ),
        'Calendar'[Date] = LastUpdatedDate
    )
)
```

[image: Result]

Same goes with the date when the status was most recently updated (we may name it something like "Status Last Updated Date").